# How to dereference a specific address in memory through dereferencing another address in memory?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, embedded, bootloader

I'm using a bootloader as a hex and s19 files in my project, so i'm not allowed to modify its content. In this bootloader there is a part implemented in the following way to verify if my application is a valid application:

```
#define CHECK_PATTERN_ADDRESS ((int32)0x00020000)
#define VALID_PATTERN             ((int16)0xE900)
#define VALID_PATTERN_MASK        ((int16)0xFF00)

    int16    pattern_data = *(int16 *)CHECK_PATTERN_ADDRESS;
    if ((pattern_data & VALID_PATTERN_MASK) == VALID_PATTERN)
    {
        //Valid application
    }
    else
    {
        //Not Valid application
    }
```

From the above code, for the bootloader to consider my application as valid, it is needed to put the valid pattern in the mentioned address "0x00020000".

This pattern is loaded directly to this address while downloading the application.

This is done by using an assembly file containing this pattern and by specifying the address where it will be loaded in the memory through the linker file.

So, currently the valid pattern is loaded successfully in the mentioned address "0x00020000" during the download process of my application.

**The main constrain is:**

The bootloader should find the valid pattern in this specific address "0x00020000"

**The problem is:**

I need to add my valid pattern in another address "let's say 0x00040000" while the DLL will keep de-referencing the data from the requested address "0x00020000" ..

Still, it is Okay for me to add any data through an assembly file to the original address "0x00020000", or to directly add any specific hex data to this address.

**The Question is:**

What can i load in this address "0x00020000", such that when the bootloader uses it in its code "as provided above" it will take the values loaded in the other address "0x00040000"

Comment: DLL? That's a Win32 thing, not embedded and certainly not related to bootloaders. In particular, DLL's run in the address space of a process. And those have _virtual_ address spaces.

Comment: Yes, you are write, i mean it is used as a hex and s19 files .. i don't have any ability to modify in its code .. i'll modify in the original post .. Thank you ..

Comment: IOW, the DLL contains an S19/hex file to burn something into an EPROM or some such, or to be used in an emulator?

Comment: To burn into EPROM .. it is used in a real target "MPC"

Comment: What lands into EPROM, should have byte at address `0x00020000` set to `0xE9` (the other byte at `0x00020001` can be set to anything, on big-endian platform .. on little-endian it's the other way around `0x00020000` being ignored and `0x00020001` must have `0xE9`). I don't get what you are asking, whatever you put in `0x00040000` will be in `0x00040000`, unless some instruction loads that value, and puts it into `0x00020000` (on the host platform). But you probably don't ask for that, you probably want to patch the source data before being burned into EPROM?

Comment: Unless you can change also the bootloader, to modify the `0x00020000` into `0x00040000`, then the 16b value at `0x00020000` will be ignored completely, and 16b value at `0x00040000` will be tested. Then again, you can then simply remove the whole check also, if you wish (if you can modify bootloader). If you can't modify bootloader, better put that `0xE900` at `0x00020000`. No way around that.

Answer (score 1):

At 0x00020000 you can put the starting point of the code that is aware of your 0x00040000 "extensions". Then, without any further midifications your bootloader will be booting that code as usualy, and that code (let's refer to it as a "secodary bootloader") will boot the code you placed under 0x00040000.